# Aframe - load a scene through click on a thumb

Tags: aframe

I am looking for a way to load an AFrame Scene through the click on a thumb.
I am trying to use a picture slider, and every picture should have a 3d scene behind it. So if i click a picture in the slider, the aframe scene should pop up in the foreground, with a different sky texture for example.
I tried multiple ways, but nothing really works. I can load a new scene through a new window, but that's not a good way.
I would appreciate any help that could lead me on the right path. :) :D

Cheers, Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an A-Frame scene in the background (or somewhere on the page) `<a-scene embedded style="z-index: -1"></a-scene>`. On the click of the picture, set the scene's `z-index` to the foreground and change whatever else you need in the scene to match the picture.

```
var aframeScene = AFRAME.scenes[0];
yourPic.addEventListener('click', function () {
  aframeScene.style.zIndex = 9999;
  aframeScene.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src', 'newImage.jpg');
});
```